# Unable to get OpenSearch to publish alerts to Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am having great difficulties in getting OpenSearch to publish alerts to Amazon SNS. I have set up the SNS topic and permissions properly, and set up the role for the SNS destination in OpenSearch per this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/alerting.html) which I called “test-OpenSearch-Role”, but when the trigger activates and tries to send an alert I get the following error in the alert:

“Error: Failed running action: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/cp-sts-grant-role/swift-us-west-2-prod-xxxxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/Test-OpenSearch-Role (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 78e679a3-7373-4fe8-b1c1-a9b5d0d9dcda; Proxy: null)”

I’m not sure what this “User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/cp-sts-grant-role/swift-us-west-2-prod-xxxxxxxxxxxx” is and I haven’t been able to get it to obtain the permissions in the “test-OpenSearch-Role” to publish to SNS. I’m not very experienced when it comes to AWS inline policies for roles but here is the JSON of the test-OpenSearch-Role:

```
{
    “Version”: “2012-10-17”,
    “Statement”: [
        {
            “Effect”: “Allow”,
            “Action”: “sts:AssumeRole”,
            “Resource”: “*"
        },
        {
            “Effect”: “Allow”,
            “Action”: “sns:Publish”,
            “Resource”: "*”
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure trust policy might be an issue. See this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-iam-policy-issues/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when trying to send alerts from OpenSearch (and Elastic Search). As suggested above, I think the issue in your case may be the lack of a trust relationship.

I got it to work by setting the role used for alerts on OpenSearch / ElasticSearch (naviation: Kibana / Dashboard => alerting => destinations => edit) up with permissions (AWS => IAM => roles => find role => permissions) using this policy for publishing to SNS:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(for resources on the sns:publish policy, you can be more specific by putting the SNS ARN instead of "*": e.g. `arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountnumber>:<name>`)

I also had to add this policy to the same role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I needed "trust relationships" (next tab from permissions in IAM) like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Furthermore, make sure you copy **the correct ARN from the role** created into the OpenSearch (Elastic Search) alert settings: I wasted much time by mistakenly putting the "Instance profile ARN" from the top-right of the role summary instead of the "ARN" (in the middle). I.e. use `arn:aws:iam::<accountnumber>:role/<rolename>` and not `arn:aws:iam::<accountnumber>:instance-profile/<rolename>`.

My error message was something like this:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::444444143907:assumed-role/cp-sts-grant-role/swift-eu-central-1-prod-005555733555 
is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: 
arn:aws:iam::005555733555:role/<myrolename> 
(Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; 
Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx; Proxy: null)"
```

...where 005555733555 is approximately my account number and 444444143907 some other account number. I didn't need to do anything particular with the other account number (such as explicitly allowing access from it)